# TSQL to get latest invoice & invoice date for customers

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to figure out how I can list out the most recent invoice date & invoice number for my customers. I have the basic structure as follows but can't figure out how to get this data. The two tables use the customer_id as the relationship

```sql
SELECT
c.customer_id
c.customer_name
( ? get most recent invoice number)
(?get most recent invoice date)

FROM
customer AS c
JOIN invoice as i on i.customer_id=c.customer_id
```

Comment: *most recent* sounds very much like `max()` ? You might want to add some sample data to clarify your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 common methods you can use. Common Table Expression (CTE) to rank all rows per customer_id order by invoice_date descending, and then you pick up date and number of the row ranked #1, or using CROSS APPLY to pick TOP 1 invoice per customer_id again, order by invoice_date descending.
Something like this

```
--  method #1 using CTE
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
    c.customer_id,
    c.customer_name, 
    i.invoice_number,
    i.invoce_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.Customer_id  ORDER BY i.invoce_date DESC)  rn
    FROM
    CUSTOMER c
    INNER JOIN invoice i on i.customer_id=c.customer_id
) 
SELECT cte.customer_id,
    cte.customer_name, 
    cte.invoice_number,
    cte.invoice_date
FROM cte 
WHERE rm = 1
-- method #2 using CROSS APPLY
SELECT
c.customer_id,
c.customer_name,
ca.invoice_number,
ca.invoice_date
FROM
customer c
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 invoice_number, invoice_date 
    FROM invoice as i WHERE i.customer_id=c.customer_id
    ORDER BY invoice_date DESC
) ca
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement to list out the most recent invoice date & invoice number per each customer could be translated to: for each customer, retrieve the invoice record that there is not exists other invoice of the same customer which has more recent invoice date. The corresponding query should be:

```
SELECT
  c.customer_id,
  c.customer_name,
  i.invoice_number,
  i.invoice_date
FROM
  customer c
  INNER JOIN invoice i ON i.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 
   FROM invoice i1
   WHERE i1.invoice_number <> i.invoice_number
      AND i1.customer_id = i.customer_id
      AND i1.invoice_date > i.invoice_date)
```